# Python : Choosing elements from a list using a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

If I have two lists

```
a = [x,y]
b = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
```

What is the easiest way to get `b[x,y]` without using `b[a]` because that returns a type error?

Comment: What are `x` and `y`?

Comment: `c = [b[aa] for aa in a]`

Comment: @ayhan great dupe!